# creating a custom Button using TouchableHighlight

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement a custom button using TouchableHighlight

I created a button class and I'm importing it into my main program like this:

In button.js:

```
export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
}
```

In app.js:

```
import Button from './button'


<View>
     <Button onPress={ () => navigate('Chat', { user: 'Abe' })} title = "Abe"
     />
</View>
```

When I run this, I just get a blank button with no text or onPress event.

How can I  pass in the onPress and title values to the Button class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the props in your Button component.

```
export default class Button extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { onPress, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              {title}
            </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, so using your example, would I keep the code in my app.js page the same?  thanks again

Comment: what CSS styles should be used so that background colour will be applied to the text only also apply border-radius

Comment: Add `backgroundColor` property to the text style. Did you try the `borderRadius` property? React Native uses slightly different names for css properties (no hyphens)

Comment: i want css applied only for text but background color is applying to entire width. if write `<Text><Text>click me</Text></Text>` then  background color is applied to text only but border radius is not applying

Comment: Sounds like your Text component is wider than you think. The backgroundColor property will only apply to the text if you style it on the text. Does the parent component have something like `alignItems: 'stretch'` set? Does the text have `alignSelf: 'stretch'` set?

Comment: ` <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => alert("pressed")}
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "red", borderRadius: 15 }}>
          Click me!
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>`  it gives me what i want but when i import this and use it align itself at center

Comment: The `alignItems: 'center'` bit will center it. I don't know what you are asking? Perhaps you should create a new question as this seems unrelated?